# InflateException: Android - Google Map - Double Click to Zoom

Tags: android, google-maps

I am showing google map in my android app. I want to zoom in when user double clicks the map.

I have xml to show Map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.is.guide.ExtMapView
    android:id="@+id/tourMapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
     android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="@string/apikey" />
```

And Class as follow

```
public class ExtMapView extends MapView {
 private Context context;
 private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public ExtMapView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(c, attrs);
  context = c;

  gestureDetector = new GestureDetector((OnGestureListener) context);
  gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener((OnDoubleTapListener) context);
 }

 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
  if (this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev))
   return true;
  else
   return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
 }
}
```

I get view.InflateException while running the app :(

What i might have missed?

Exception as follow

```
12-07 21:26:09.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6714): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.is.guide/com.is.TourMapActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class 
com.is.guide.ExtMapView

12-07 21:26:09.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6714): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.is.guide.ExtMapView
```

I referred this link
 http://dev.kafol.net/2011/11/how-hard-is-it-to-make-simple-zoom-in.html

Comment: What's the exact logcat output?

Comment: Added exception to above question

Comment: What is the package name for ExtMapView?

Comment: did you add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` under `application` tag?

Comment: Raghav, i did mistake in namespace. thanks

Answer (score 0):

override all constructors

```
public ExtMapView(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    super(arg0, arg1);
    init(arg0);
}

public ExtMapView(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
    super(arg0, arg1);
    init(arg0);
}

public ExtMapView(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    init(arg0);
}

protected void init(Context c) {
    context = c;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector((OnGestureListener) context);
    gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener((OnDoubleTapListener) context);
}
```

verify too in your manifest.xml if you have the follow tag

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

and if the packge name on xml "*you put com.is.guide.*" is the correct.

Comment: Package name was wrong in my XML. such a silly mistake.. resolved thanks

Comment: @iShare good that the problem was solved. but I recommend you overwrite all constructors when you create a custom view.